# configure eclipse indigo cvs for one workspace referencing two cvs servers with differing cvs_server

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I would like one workspace to have connections to two cvs servers.  One is running on Solaris and it requires a setting in Window > Preferences > Team > CVS > Ext Connection Method > CVS_SERVER "/opt/csw/bin/cvs".

The other cvs server runs on Linux and it requires the setting Window > Preferences > Team > CVS > Ext Connection Method > CVS_SERVER "/usr/bin/cvs".  (Actually the Linux server probably doesn't require this setting at all, it would probably work with the default path.  But on Solaris the default path for an SSH login will not include the path to CVS so the setting is required for the Solaris connection.)

Is there any way to make the "CVS_SERVER" setting specific to the connection so that one workspace can support the two different settings?

Of course I know that symbolic links on one or both servers could make the two servers appear to have identical paths to cvs, but I am hoping to find a solution on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

While I wait for a better solution, my current work-around is to change the settings of Window > Preferences > Team > CVS > Ext Connection Method > CVS_SERVER when I need to access the less frequently used repository, then change settings back to use my more frequently used repository.

Ugly but it works.